# How to calculate Profit Margin in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

How do I calculate Profit Margin From this Pandas Dataframe, I know that the formula is

**Profit Margin = Net_Profit/Revenue**

But How do I identify Net_Profit from this DataFrame

```
Asset     Earnings_Bf_Interest_n_Taxes  Net Income(Loss)         Revenue             Market Value   
1067.633       86.708                    58.660                 1061.169               1226.1925    
1703.727       137.016                   69.826 1775.782        1049.8206              -0.125510
1515.000      -8.600                     10.200 1594.300        1046.3954               0.009514
```

•   **EBIT -- Earnings Before Interest and Taxes**

Comment: Are you sure you have all the columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add column based on another column value / math. operation between them.

```
df['Profit Margin'] = df['Net Income(Loss)'] / df['Revenue']
```